# InkCanvas slows down when we have multiple strokes

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, inkcanvas

I am using InkCanvas for creating paint like application. When i use to draw multiple strokes on canvas it works very slow.

I have machine with very good configuration as : `Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz (4CPUs),~2.4GHz and 2GB RAM.`

When i have more that 10000 thousands strokes memory usage goes up to 500 MB and while drawing and erasing CPU uses cross 30 . Normal samples also gives the same result.Re-sizing of window is also very slow. I chose `InkCanvas` because i need to create vector based drawing application and WPF have provided it.

What is the reason behind this ? Should i go with InkCanvas for paint like application? If yes then how should I tackle this problem?

Comment: is [this](http://www.vistax64.com/avalon/902-drawingcontext-close-very-slow-many-geometries-drawn.html) helpful?

Comment: We are not dealing with any drawing context. we are directly using WPF InkCanvas.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own canvas for the job, not inkcanvas. It is designed for light usage.